# Is tracing or drawing using a grid legitimate in photoshop

Tags: design-principles

I use photoshop for web design, though I would really like to try and create faces with it. Though I can not draw. I saw a video on youtube where they traced over a photograph with a pen tool. and another one used a grid and drew the image. (and the of course the colours and the tones are created uniquely)

So if I take a picture of my self, trace it and paint it. Would that be legitimate to be shown in my portfolio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it legitimate to have in your portfolio? Of course - your portfolio and the skills it shows off, is what you say it is. Nothing is illegitimate.

And if you're talking about 'meshing' in Illustrator, it is certainly something you should show off, if you can indeed pull it off. I've seen people do perfect vector drawings of celebrities, and that certainly takes massive amounts of skill.

Comment: thanks. Ha since I have written this question I have been working on it and it is very hard (I thought it be easy). But now that you say that I am definitely going to try and learn this - thanks man